# How to fix gradle failed sync new android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I try to fix this problems but still get the same errors over and over again. Am new in android studio, I need help to fix this errors in order to continue learning and create new project.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Clean -> rebuild or Invalidate cache and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54730387/8770663)

You can also try the following as well:

```
Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Then you can sync gradle.

```
Gradle tab -> Refresh all gradle projects
```

That should help you get back all your dependencies.

Comment: Gradle project failed sync