# How to fix broken imports?

Tags: java, android

I've been building an app in android studio for months now, and I fire up the application tonight. I get the entire list of imports all in red and I don't know why. What governs things like.

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

How can I get it working again?

Comment: sdk not setup properly? sdk not found on disk? ... can be lots of things

Comment: Check your Android SDK setup.

Comment: ok, check the sdk for what

Comment: @Eeveeking I think you may need to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try the following as well:

```
Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Then you can sync gradle.

```
Gradle tab -> Refresh all gradle projects
```

That should help you get back all your dependencies.

Comment: ok, it seems to have almost fixed itself just now, not sure what any of that was about but thanks for the support of all you!

Comment: Sometimes the caches get corrupted or messed up and it requires this process to get things back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment all of your dependencies in your build.gradle and sync. Then uncomment them and sync again. This solve your problem.